# Getting region list for Azure AKS using SDK

Tags: azure, go, azure-aks

I'm trying to get the list of regions supported for Azure AKS cluster using azure Go SDK. I have went through the code couldn't find any samples. From the code, I tried to get NewRegionClient and use API ListByService and getting an error saying missing Authorization header. I set the subscriptionID when I create NewRegionClient. Here is my code

```
 regions := make([]Region, 0)

 //Microsoft.ContainerService
 rc := apimanagement.NewRegionClient(acm.azureCluster.ServicePrincipal.SubscriptionID)
 ctx := context.Background()
 result, err := rc.ListByService(ctx, "resource-name", "ContainerService")
 if err != nil {
 log.Error(err)
 }

 log.Info(result)
 return regions, nil
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is no SDK for all the language to get the support regions of AKS, at least the python and go. What you need to do is not to find the support regions, but find the support AKS versions in the region you want. Maybe you can try to use [`OrchestratorVersionProfileListResult`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/profiles/latest/containerservice/mgmt/containerservice#OrchestratorVersionProfileListResult) to list the available versions in the region you want.

Comment: To get the OrchestratorVersionProfileList I need to ContainerServicesClient I create the client like below ```createcss := containerservice.NewContainerServicesClient(acm.azureCluster.ServicePrincipal.SubscriptionID)``` but still I'm getting missing Authorization header error.

Comment: @SriThuraisamy I do not know how you authenticate. But you can follow the authentication steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/go/azure-sdk-go-authorization).

Comment: My bad. I missed to set the principal ID. Getting Kubernetes version for given region is working. For Region still have issue on API version error. I can use Kube version to filter. Thanks for your help